# Displaying HTML Body of an email

Tags: python, html, django, html-email

I am building a website using Python Django and would like to display emails.

The emails are processed in the backend and are retrieved by ajax in JSON format.
How can I safely display the html body of an email without destroying my main theme?

I thought of implementing the email with iframes `<iframe sandbox="">` . Are there other (better) ways to implement the html body without running into danger to compromise my website?

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize the HTML: Use a library like bleach in Django to sanitize and filter out potentially harmful HTML and JavaScript from the email's HTML body. This way, you can ensure that only safe content is displayed. Here's a basic example:

```
import bleach

email_html = "<p>Your email content here</p>"
sanitized_html = bleach.clean(email_html, tags=['p', 'strong', 'em'], attributes={'p': ['style']})
```

Customize the allowed tags and attributes according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like `bleach` sanitize the HTML content before rendering it. This ensures that potentially malicious or unwanted content, such as JavaScript, is removed. After sanitizing the content, you can render it directly in your template.

```
import bleach

def sanitize_render_email_html(email_html):
    content = bleach.clean(email_html, tags=bleach.ALLOWED_TAGS, attributes=bleach.ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES)
    return content
```

Or use, `DOMPurify` for sanitization and then render the content in a HTML structure.

```
import dompurify

def sanitize_render_email_html(email_html):
    content = dompurify.sanitize(email_html)
    return content
```

In your Django template:

```
<div>
    {{ content | safe }}
</div>
```

Instead of iframes, you can display the email content in a modal or popover that overlays your main theme. This keeps the email content isolated from your main theme but provides a better user experience.

You can use JavaScript libraries like Bootstrap's modal or create a custom modal with CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I can't follow you with the modal. The main style would still override the styles in an email body, even in a modal.

Comment: I don't know Django, but I do know email. What Gmail and others will do is add a prefix to all the CSS, unique to each email. All id and class references within each email will have the same prefix, including in the `<style>`  blocks. They also apply a reset for this area globally. That mitigates the main page style override issue.